# UriMatcher pattern for arbitrary strings, not URI's

Tags: android, string-comparison

I can't help noticing that I'm using quite a lot of string comparisons while parsing a well defined XML file in Android (with a `XmlPullParser`).

As of now it typically looks something like this (somewhat simplified):

```
...
tag = parser.getName().toLowerCase();
if ("tag1".equals(tag)) {
    // Do something with the state machine
}
else if ("tag2".equals(tag)) {
    // Do something else with the state machine
}

...

else if ("tag23".equals(tag)) {
    // Do something more with the state machine
}
```

What I would like to have instead is something like this (where StringMatcher would be the hypothetical happy-maker for me):

```
private static final StringMatcher tagMatcher = new StringMatcher(StringMatcher.NO_MATCH);

static {
    tagMatcher.addString("tag1", 1);
    tagMatcher.addString("tag2", 2);
    ....
    tagMatcher.addString("tag23", 23);
}

...

tag = parser.getName().toLowerCase();
switch (tagMatcher.match(tag)) {
    case 1:
        // Do something with the state machine
        break;
    case 2:
        // Do something else with the state machine
        break;
    ...
    case 23:
        // Do something more with the state machine
        break;
    default:
        Log.e("PARSER", "Unexpected tag: " + tag);
        break;
}
```

As you see I would like a `UriMatcher` pattern applied to my XML file tags. Do any of you know of such a class I can use in Android? Any other fast filtering on strings would do as well (it would be neat, though, if the UriMatcher-pattern could be reused).

So far I've been looking at regular expressions but I'm not really sure I can fit it to my needs (I would like a switch - case style test) and, of course, the regular string comparison as shown in above example.

Cheers,
  -- dbm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use a `HashMap` since that does not need to iterate over the whole array to find the match value

```
private static final HashMap<String, Integer> tagMatcher =
        new HashMap<String, Integer>();

static {
    tagMatcher.put("tag1", 1);
    tagMatcher.put("tag2", 2);
    tagMatcher.put("tag23", 23);
}

private void parse (String node) {
    Integer value = tagMatcher.get(node);
    int match = value != null ? value.intValue() : 0;
    switch (match) {
        case 1:
            // etc
            break;
        case 0: // no match
            break;
    }
}
```

or you can use a `SparseIntArray` using the same hash approach. Advantage here is that you don't need to box `int` into `Integer` which should result in a slight speed / memory advantage.

```
private static final SparseIntArray tagMatcher2 = new SparseIntArray();
private static void put(String key, int value) {
    tagMatcher2.put(key.hashCode(), value);
}
private static int get(String key) {
    return tagMatcher2.get(key.hashCode());
}
static {
    put("tag1", 1);
    put("tag2", 2);
    put("tag23", 23);
}

private void parse2 (String node) {
    switch (get(node)) {
        case 1:
            // etc
            break;
        case 0: // no match
            break;
    }
}
```

This is doing binary search instead of iterating over the whole thing like `SparseArray#indexOfValue(t)` does. Note that there is a chance of hash collisions in this approach.

I think using an approach like that is faster than a long chain of `if (equals) else if (equals)` for larger amounts of comparisons. The `if .. else if` approach needs to check `String.equals()` every time which boils down to comparing all characters of the strings while a hash based approach needs to calculate the hash value just once and can do a binary search over all known hash values then.

Comment: beautiful... *looking-for-better-superlatives*
Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `SparseArray`

```
 static{
        tagmatcher.append(0, "tag1");
        tagmatcher.append(1, "tag2");
    }

  switch(tagmatcher.keyAt(tagmatcher.indexOfValue(tag))){
           case 0:
             break;

           case 1:
             break
        }
```

But if you are going to add consecutive indexes you can always use an ArrayList